# Orbbec Astra with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, orbbec

I am using Orbbec Astra Unity SDK 2.1.3
I want to create an app in which the user will stand infront of the sensor and can change the cloths model on the screen with swipe gesture.
I am trying to do it but facing many difficulties as there is no proper documentation for the sdk I found.
And no content on net.
Whatever I found was the old content which does not exist in the latest sdk.
its taking much time for me to understand the scripts and manipulate them.
so can some help me to make the above functionality possible.?

I have got the positions of the joints of the skeleton to place the cloth model in it.
Now I want to get the depth so that I can make the model look more natural. Right now it is looking as plan.
or it would be more helpful if I could get the right path to follow to achieve this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: Your question lacks enough detail for anyone to give help that is likely to be useful. Please read the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [ask] for guidance on editing your question to make it possible and easy for people to help you.